# How to set visibility of the textview using android espresso test

Tags: android, testing, textview, visibility, android-espresso

I want to set visibility for the text view from test cases.I am using espresso for testing the UI. I used the viewAction to set the text to the text view. But I want to set visibility for the text view. Please, any one helps me to resolve this issue.
Here is my code for setting the text to the text view.

```
public ViewAction setTextInTextView(final String value){
    return new ViewAction() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
            ((TextView) view).setText(value);
        }

        @Override
        public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return allOf(isDisplayed(), isAssignableFrom(TextView.class));
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "replace text";
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: `((TextView) view).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` or `((TextView) view).setVisibility(View.GONE);`?

Comment: If i use like that ...iam getting this Error ....  android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'replace text' on view 'Animations or transitions are enabled on the target device.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this,

```
public class MainActivityInstrumentationTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void validateEditText() {

        onView(withId(R.id.out)).perform(setTextViewVisibitity(true));

        // Just for viewing the results. Remove after use.
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        onView(withId(R.id.out)).perform(setTextViewVisibitity(false));

        // Just for viewing the results. Remove after use.
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static ViewAction setTextViewVisibitity(final boolean value) {
        return new ViewAction() {

            @Override
            public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
                return isAssignableFrom(TextView.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
                view.setVisibility(value ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public String getDescription() {
                return "Show / Hide View";
            }
        };
    }
}
```